# How Grails create methods at run time Ex obj.setName("Abhay)

Tags: java, grails, reflection

I want to know how Grails create Dynamic methods , there are alot of methods that are created by Grails Framework at run time , like setters and getters , dynamic finders etc . I know about Reflection in java , but never read anything like that , 
If there any thing you find then please provide me link

Comment: This is a very large topic called "Metaprogramming" and is one of the reasons Grails uses Groovy. You could start by understanding the concept: http://beta.groovy-lang.org/docs/groovy-2.3.0/html/documentation/core-metaprogramming.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of it is based on [Groovy runtime metaclass programming](http://groovy.codehaus.org/JN3525-MetaClasses). Have a look at `AbstractGormApi` and its implementations in Grails , you can find there most of the methods injected in runtime to all domain classes to perform all the magic tricks Grails does.

Comment: There's actually very little runtime metaprogramming in domain classes - only the methods whose names are dynamic and based on persistent field names, e.g. `findAllByFooAndBar`. You're correct that `AbstractGormApi` and its subclasses are the sources for domain class methods, but those are mixed into the domain classes at _compile_ time with AST transformations. The same thing happens in controllers and taglibs - very little runtime metaprogramming, and a lot of compile-time metaprogramming